# JAAS and acess from android

Tags: android, jboss, jersey, jboss6.x, jaas

Hi i have secured my server using JAAS and i have performed the web authentification ,
now i have to authenticate from mobile application using android app , how  can we use the Rest web services after authentication , is JAAS support access from mobile app ? 
i have a ws that allow me to verify if the login and password are corect ; haw can i access this ws ?
on the web app there is the container authentification so after doing this , i am allowed to use all my ws 
is there any thing like this  on android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was solved by performing a ws that get authrization from the server and when i call a ws i usuly give it a query param wich is the login and pass  , so  the server verify if the user is authorised to  do the operation or not , using JAAS i have the annotation @rolesallawed on the top of each method .