# JAAS for android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have a java code which has to be ported to android. Java code uses JAAS for security but javax.security libraries are missing for android. So, I compiled javax.security libraries separately and added to android libs. Now, I see that loginContext.login() gives null pointer exception. Is it a code issue or are there any other dependencies on android to make it work?. Will repackaging jars (which I did)  work for all libraries which are missing in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

> The main goal of JAAS is to separate the concerns of user
>   authentication so that they may be managed independently. While the
>   former authentication mechanism contained information about where the
>   code originated from and who signed that code, JAAS adds a marker
>   about who runs the code. By extending the verification vectors JAAS
>   extends the security architecture for Java applications that require
>   authentication and authorization modules.

But With Android as Referenced [jeffsix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121356/jeffsix) or this [AhmedDrira resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349455/jaas-and-acess-from-android)

> JAAS doesn't really apply to Android. JAAS provides user-centric
>   security to Java-based applications (who is the identity - usually a
>   "user" such as an LDAP user id - that is "running" the application and
>   are they allowed to do what they are trying to). In Android, user IDs
>   are used differently in that each application runs with a different
>   user ID in order to separate the applications from each other. As
>   there are very different concepts of identity between a JAAS-enabled
>   Java application and an Android application, the JAAS model doesn't
>   reconcile well with the Android model, hence the warnings in the docs.

for details please refer [jeffsixPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636599/using-jaas-java-authentication-and-authorization-service-on-android) answer

Comment: In other words user1352179 is barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: I had read his comment earlier. But,I still has the doubt why it won't work. If each application has its own user ID's , can't I use it for sake of porting the code?. If no, which are the libraries that can be used as an alternative to JAAS for android?

Comment: @user1352179 that's fodder for a whole other SO question, and a good one.

Comment: Is that the reason for NUllPointerException?